# Expressão Regular para capturar depois da última barra

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho a seguinte URL:

```
("file:///home/pasta/pasta/img/intro-bg.jpg")
```

Gostaria de saber que expressão regular posso usar para capturar apenas o `intro-bg.jpg`

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Um `split()` por barra não resolve? o último elemento é a imagem.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a expressão regular:

```
/\/([^/]*)$/
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776979/regex-get-all-characters-after-last-slash-in-url

Comment: Se quiser evitar a utilização de Submatches (ou Groups), tente usar esta expressão: `(?!\/)[^\/]+\/?$` que somente adiciona um negative lookahead na expressão regular. O demo do [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mblcCW/2).

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma:

```js
const str = "file:///home/pasta/pasta/img/intro-bg.jpg";
const basename = str.replace(/^.*\//g, '');
console.log(basename);
```

Comment: Ao usuario que saiu distribundo downvotes, por favor deixe seu comentario.